# python how to show slowly each letter of a string in random order

Tags: python, logic

yes i know replace methods is not what i need but i don't know how to do it, it must to show the letters from a word, slowly, below the code i type the output what i want

````
import random
a = "hello"
x = "_" * len(a)
c = x.replace(x[random.randint(0, len(a) -1 )], a[random.randint(0, len(a) - 1)])
print(c)```


the output what i want is something like 

_____
2seconds later
__ll_
2sl...
h_ll_
2....
hell_
2...
hello
````

Comment: How do you want it to determine what letters to show in what order?

Comment: randomly in any order in specific

Comment: And if a letter is in the original word more than once it shows all of them in one go?

Comment: yes! is very difficult to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it various ways: by replacing, by indexing, by regex ...

A simple implementation using a regex that reads from a whitelist:

```
from random import shuffle
from time import sleep
from re import sub

word, mask_char, whitelist = ("hello", '_', '')
char_list = list(word)
sleep_time = 2

# Mix the order of the letters.
shuffle(char_list)  

# Make the letters from the list unique,
# then make it a list again, for indexing later:
char_list  = list(set(char_list))   

# Print the full mask:
print(mask_char*len(word))
sleep(sleep_time)

for ch in char_list:
    whitelist += ch
    print(sub(fr"[^{whitelist}]", mask_char, word))
    if ch != char_list[-1]:
        sleep(sleep_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need the time module for the sleep function. Then it's just a matter of getting each letter in the `a` string, shuffling them, looping through them and then each iteration you loop over `a` and replace the letter in x.

I made `x` a list due to strings being immutable in python.

```
from random import sample
from time import sleep

a = "hello"
x = ["_" for _ in a]
letters = frozenset(a)

for letter in sample(letters, len(letters)):
    print(''.join(x))
    for i, replace in enumerate(a):
        if replace == letter:
            x[i] = letter
    sleep(2)
print(''.join(x))
```

Comment: woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow you're a master, thx a lot